# How to add new value with same key to document

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I need to write down a category and its cost in category object. Now, in my code example, I am adding the products: $50 category to the user. After execution, 'categories': { products: '50$' } is displayed in the console. But if you add products: 1000$ again, it will overwrite and output 'categories': { products: '1000$' }. And I need to display 'categories': { products: '$50' , products: '$1000' }. How can this be implemented?

```js
mongoClient.connect(function (err, client) {
  if (err) return console.log(err);

  const db = client.db("db");
  const col = db.collection("coll");
  col.findOneAndUpdate(
    {
      name: "User1",
    },
    {
      $set: {
        "сategories.products": "50$",
      },
    },
    function (err, result) {
      console.log(result);
      client.close();
    }
  );
});
```

Comment: as far as I know, object keys must be unique in javascript, it will overwrite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```js
$set: {
  "сategories.products": "50$"
}
```

use

```js
$addToSet: {
  сategories: {
    products: "1000$"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well if I understood you correctly you have an object like `categories:{products:$50}` but you want that whenever you post a new price it should get added to the object not overwrite it.

I think that is not possible either every time you create a new object like `{products1:$50, products2:$1000}` and set your categories field to be equal to this new object

**OR**

you should make your model like `categories:{products:[]}`. So, that you can just push the new price in the array.